# hook_field_access VS ['#access'] in hook_form_alter

Tags: forms, drupal-7, field

What is the difference in "setting field access" between the two different hooks mentioned in title?

Where are any docs about it? (On the two hooks page did not find any way to get get to the answer.)

I rephrase the question: What is the HTML result of one or the other hook?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[#access](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#access)** is an Form API attribute (your can add it to form elements using hook_form_alter()).

When set to FALSE, the element is not rendered (Drupal will not render field HTML in a form) and the user submitted value is not taken into consideration.

Example:

```
function MYMODULE_form_node_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  $form['some_field']['#access'] = FALSE; // this field will not be rendered in node edit form
}
```

**[hook_field_access()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_access/7)** is a hook, which determines whether the user has access to a given field. With this hook you can disallow some user access (view and edit) some field:

```
function MYMODULE_field_access($op, $field, $entity_type, $entity, $account) {
  if ($entity_type == 'node') {
    if ($field['field_name'] == 'SOME_FIELD') {
      if ($account->uid == 100) {
        return FALSE;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This means that SOME FIELD will not be rendered for user with uid=100 when he **edit and view** nodes.

...or disallow everyone to edit some field:

```
function MYMODULE_field_access($op, $field, $entity_type, $entity, $account) {
  if ($entity_type == 'node') {
    if ($field['field_name'] == 'SOME_FIELD') {
      if ($op == 'edit') {
        return FALSE;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The code above will actually set '#access' attribute of element 'SOME_FIELD' in node edit form to FALSE, so nobody will see this field in node edit form.

So '#access' attribute has only one use case - setting access to a given form field.

hook_field_access() has a more vast area of applications, *including* manipulation of '#access' attribute.